# Java Error despues de presionar boton para agregar campos en un JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing

gracias por informarme. He transcrito la pregunta por si había más gente con el mismo problema.
**TÍTULO: Java error después de presionar botón para añadir más campos a un formulario.**

¿podéis ayudarme con el siguiente error, por favor?
Would anyone help me with this error, please?

Expodré mi caso (Estoy aprendiendo Java)
I'll expose my case (I'm learning java at the moment):

Así es como se ejecuta wl programa:
This is how the program runs

[image: This is how the program runs]

Así es cóml debería/quiero que se ejecutw el programa: (Al presionar en +, debería añadir otra lía de campos, pero me aparece un error)
This is how I want the program to run

[image: This is how I want the program to run]

**Debugger Console:**

Listening on javadebug

User program running

User program finished

**Error(debug):**

```
debug:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1093)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:417)
    at appimp.EPanel$1.actionPerformed(EPanel.java:157)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 25 seconds)
```

**1. MAIN PROGRAM:**

```
package appimp;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import com.toedter.calendar.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrycia
 * main class that is a Jframe
 */

public class Vformulario extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Vformulario
     */
    // VARIABLES
    private JPanel Continente;

    public Vformulario() {
        super();                    
        configurarVentana();        // windows setup
        formul();
    }

    private void configurarVentana() {
        this.setTitle("Formulario de Imputaciones");            
        this.setSize(900, 350);                                 
        this.setResizable(true);                               
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    }

    public void formul() {
        Continente = new JPanel();
        Continente.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(Continente);
        Continente.setLayout(new BorderLayout());;
        JTabbedPane jt = new JTabbedPane();

        jt.add("ESPAÑA", new EPanel());
        jt.add("MÉXICO", new MPanel());

        add(jt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //                           
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }//                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vformulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vformulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vformulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vformulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //

        /* Create and display the form */

        Vformulario ventana=new Vformulario();
        ventana.setVisible(true);

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**3. EPanel java class**

Aquí es dónde me aparece el error. Según creo.

```java
package appimp;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import com.toedter.calendar.*;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrycia
 */
public class EPanel extends JPanel {

    //private JComboBox comboProyecto, comboNombre, comboH;
    private JComboBox comboNombre;
    //declarar arrays de los objetos del formulario que se van a repetir
    private JComboBox[] comboProyecto, comboH;
    private JTextField[] textField;
    private JDateChooser[] diaC;

    private JLabel nombre, proyecto, descripcion, horas, dia, aniadir;
    //private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel contenedor, sur, centro;
    private JButton Baniadir, Belim;
    private int count = 0;
    private int max_row = 20;
    private String[] LosProy = {"alejandro", "berenice", "juan", "ana", "bartolo", "diana", "cesar"};

    public EPanel() {
        contenedor = new JPanel();
        centro = new JPanel();
        sur = new JPanel();
        //definir título de contenedor
        contenedor.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 5),"ESTÁS EN ESPAÑA"));
        add(contenedor);
        contenedor.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contenedor, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
        contenedor.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        //declarar un array de todos los componentes que se van a repetir
        comboProyecto = new JComboBox[20];
        textField = new JTextField[20];
        comboH = new JComboBox[20];
        diaC = new JDateChooser[20];

        //PANEL QUE CONTIENE EL NOMBRE DEL QUE IMPUTA
        contenedor.add(centro);
            centro.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            nombre = new JLabel("Selecciona tu nombre:");
            nombre.setFont(font);
            comboNombre=new JComboBox();
                comboNombre.addItem("Javier");
                comboNombre.addItem("Jesús");
                comboNombre.addItem("Patricia");
                comboNombre.addItem("Kevin");

            centro.add(nombre);
            centro.add(comboNombre);

        //PANEL QUE CONTIENE EL FORMULARIO DONDE SE IMPUTA
        contenedor.add(sur);
            sur.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,7,5,10));
            sur.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

            proyecto = new JLabel("Nombre del Proyecto:");
            proyecto.setFont(font);
            descripcion = new JLabel("Breve descripción de la tarea:");
            descripcion.setFont(font);
            horas = new JLabel("Horas empleadas:");
            horas.setFont(font);
            dia = new JLabel("Día de la semana:");
            dia.setFont(font);
            aniadir = new JLabel("Añade más filas:");
            aniadir.setFont(font);  

            Baniadir = new JButton("+");
            Baniadir.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
            Belim = new JButton("-");
            Belim.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,10));

            comboProyecto[count] = new JComboBox(LosProy);
            comboProyecto[count].setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel());
                comboProyecto[count].setEditable(true);
                AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.comboProyecto[count]);
            textField[count] = new JTextField();
            comboH[count] = new JComboBox();
                double Hmax = 16;
                double h =0.5;
                comboH[count]=new JComboBox();
                    for (int i = 1; i < Hmax; i++) {
                        comboH[count].addItem(h);
                        h=h+0.5;
                    }
            diaC[count] = new JDateChooser();
            //cambpo de fecha con máscara
                diaC[count] = new JDateChooser("dd/MM/yyyy", "##/##/####", '_');

            sur.add(proyecto);
            sur.add(descripcion);
            sur.add(horas);
            sur.add(dia);
            sur.add(aniadir);
            sur.add(Baniadir);
            sur.add(Belim);
            sur.add(comboProyecto[count]);
            sur.add(textField[count]);
            sur.add(comboH[count]);
            sur.add(diaC[count]);

    //add the listener to the jbutton to handle the "pressed" event
    Baniadir.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if(count == max_row-1){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maximum of 20 rows can be added","Failed!!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
              return;
            }
            count++;
            sur.add(comboProyecto[count]);
            sur.add(textField[count]);
            sur.add(comboH[count]);
            sur.add(diaC[count]);
            sur.revalidate();
            sur.repaint();
        }
    });

    Belim.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if(count > -1){ // Deleting one row at a time
            sur.remove(comboProyecto[count]);
            sur.remove(textField[count]);
            sur.remove(comboH[count]);
            sur.remove(diaC[count]);
            count--;
            sur.revalidate();
            sur.repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: Amiga, estas haciendo la pregunta en stackoverflow en español. Te invito a que la preguntes en tu idioma (ingles) en el siguiente enlace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario. No pensé que fuese un problema. He transcrito mi pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: te falta agregar la clase MPanel. Y de donde sacas esta clase JDateChooser??

Comment: @Patricia no es que sea un problema, solo que deberias realizar la pregunta en el idioma que es, y este es en español :D

Comment: @josego la clase JDateChooser viene dentro de un jar, JCalendar de toedter. La clase MPanel no me da problema aún porque no la tengo hecha jejeje está en blanco, vamos. La que me está dando fallo es la de EPanel(). Un saludo.

Comment: @Patricia podrías poner bien el código EPanel java class porque me salen errores de sintaxis. gracias

Comment: @josego perdona, qué errores de sintaxis? Lo he copiado tal cual lo tengo T.T

Comment: @Patricia la parte del for (int i = 1; i  -1){ // Deleting one row at a time y  esto no se donde cierra.  });??

Comment: @josego muchas gracias por el comentario. Acabo de repasar lo que he publicado y veo que no coincide con lo que tengo. Parece que se han cortado cosas. En cuanto pueda lo actualizo. Perdonad el error.

Comment: @josego he actualizado el código. Cada vez que intentaba ponerlo entre las etiquetas "pre" había trozos en el final que se cortaban. Lo he añadido con un "snipet". Espero que ahora se visualice como es debido.

Comment: explota dentro de Baniadir, en la parte sur.add(comboProyecto[count]);. No entiendo porque haces así. te recomendaría que utilices JTable que te va a facilitar mucho mas.

Comment: @josego gracias por el comentario. Tenía pensado hacer más tarde el ejercicio con JTable. Pero primero quiero aprender a que me funcione de esta manera. Para seguir mejorando. Puedes indicarme en qué aspecto falla? No entiendo por qué al intentar añadir el campo se produce el erro. Estaría agradecida si me dejases una pista de lo que le ocurre a lo mejor. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que no estas inicializando el arreglo completamente:

```
private int count = 0; // el indice
private JComboBox[] comboProyecto, comboH; // declaras el arreglo

comboProyecto = new JComboBox[20]; // creas el arreglo con 20 datos

comboProyecto[count] = new JComboBox(LosProy); // comboProyecto[0], ¿que pasa con los otros 19 elementos? -> no están inicializados(comboProyecto[1] = null)
comboProyecto[count].setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel());
comboProyecto[count].setEditable(true);

public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (count == max_row - 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maximum of 20 rows can be added", "Failed!!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        count++; // count = 1
        sur.add(comboProyecto[count]); // comboProyecto[1] -> nunca fue inicializado = null -> entonces JVM: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        sur.add(textField[count]);
        sur.add(comboH[count]);
        sur.add(diaC[count]);
        sur.revalidate();
        sur.repaint();
}
```

La solución es muy simple:

```
public EPanel() {
// tus otras declaraciones
private int count = 0; // el indice
private JComboBox[] comboProyecto, comboH; // declaras el arreglo
comboProyecto = new JComboBox[20]; // creas el arreglo con 20 datos
// antes del listener del botón 
for (int i = 0; i &lt 20; i++)
  comboProyecto[i] = new JComboBox();
  // codigo extra
}
```